# Hibernate Session.save() doesn't return a value?

Tags: java, hibernate

Below code throws a casting error

> Long newID = (Long)session.save(object);

I am new to hibernate. Don't know why.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The return value of `session.save()` depends on your mapping. Most likely you have a type of ID that isn't a Long. Try doing this:

```
System.out.println(session.save(object).getClass().getName());
```

Then you'll see the type name.

Comment: how to know if save performed or not? Is there any check in hibernate like the normal JDBC PreparedStatement count

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods:

1. `public Serializable save(Object object) throws HibernateException`
   Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with `cascade="save-update"`.
   **Parameters:** object - a transient instance of a persistent class
   **Returns:** the generated identifier
2. `public Serializable save(String entityName, Object object) throws HibernateException`
   Persist the given transient instance, first assigning a generated identifier. (Or using the current value of the identifier property if the assigned generator is used.) This operation cascades to associated instances if the association is mapped with `cascade="save-update"`.
   **Parameters:** object - a transient instance of a persistent class
   **Returns:** the generated identifier